# what would I use in this situation(asp.net mvc 3 display templates)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, display-templates

I have something like this

```
public class ViewModel1
{
   // some properties here
   public List<ViewModel2> ViewModel2 {get; set;}
}

public class ViewModel2
{
   public string A {get; set;}
   public string B {get; set;}
}

// view

<table>
  <thead>
     <tr> a </tr>
     <tr> b </tr>
  </thead>
   <tbody>
      // want to use a display template to render table row and cells so I don't need to use for loop 
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried to use "`@Html.DisplayForModel()`" but that I seems to take the viewModel of the view(so in my case ViewModel1)

I need to make it take ViewModel2 but I don't see any option to pass in ViewModel2(a model object).

I then tried

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ViewModel2)
```

That did not work to well it just printed out like the first properties value and never even made any cells.

Here is basically my display template

```
@model ViewModel2

  <tr>
        <td>@Model.A</td>
        <td>@Model.B</td>
 </tr>
```

So how can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>b</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ViewModel2)
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and then inside `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/ViewModel2.cshtml`:

```
@model ViewModel2
<tr>
    <td>@Model.A</td>
    <td>@Model.B</td>
</tr>
```

Notice the name and location of the display template. It is important to respect this convention if you want this to work.

Comment: Why does it have to go into the shared folder? It is not a shared template in my case.

Comment: @chobo2, not necessary, it could go also in the `~/Views/SomeControllerName/EditorTemplates/ViewModel2.cshtml`.

Comment: Thats where I have it except in DisplayTemplates not Edit. They all have the same names though.

Comment: @chobo2, oops, yes indeed DisplayTemplates.

Answer (score 0):

If you REALLY don't want the foreach in your "main" template, you can tag your property with UIHint

```
public class ViewModel1
{
   // some properties here
   [UIHint("ListOfViewModel2")]
   public List<ViewModel2> ViewModel2 {get; set;}
}
```

Then, in DisplayTemplates\ListOfViewModel2.ascx, you put your foreach

```
@model IList<ViewModel2>

foreach( var m in Model )
{
    <tr>@Html.DisplayFor(x => m)</tr>
}
```

Dont change your DisplayModel for ViewModel2, and in you view, you can call

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ViewModel2)
```

Comment: @mathieu - well it's not that I really don't want to put a foreach loop in my main(if I don't have to thats great if I do that is ok). It more the fact that doing it this way solves the problem with the "name" attribute otherwise I got to make a counter to make sure the names are different. So you know a way around that looks good then I might go that way. I will look into what you have but I don't get what "ListOfViewModel2" is.

Comment: Its the name of the template file. By default, property type name is  used. When you have properties of type like "IList<Something>", you can't name a file "IList<Something>.ascx". So you put an UIHint on the property to tell ASP.NET MVC which displaytemplate to use.

Comment: @mathieu - Ok I put my UiHint with my template file name. I put @Html.DisplayForModel() and changed my template to have a foreach loop. However it still is using the wrong viewModel. It still is using ViewModel1 for the DisplayForModel template. It's not using my ViweModel2 template

Comment: @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ViewModel2)

Comment: @mathieu - Tried that too but all id's and names have same names what is not valid html.

Comment: @chobo2 - So you absolutely need valid html?  why?

Comment: I don't see any id generated in your display template ?

Comment: @jfar  - I like to keep standards.@mathieu - Yes in my code it would not. In my real code I am using checkboxfor() that generates a name and id.